# Why would this query take 8 times as long to run as this other query?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 on Azure.

I two very simple queries:

```
UPDATE dbo.Datasets
SET Category = 'KLM'
```

&

```
UPDATE dbo.Datasets
SET CategoryAlt = 'DLM'
```

Table `dbo.Datasets` has approximately 3 millions records.

Category column is of type `varchar(250)`, `CategoryAlt` is of type `varchar(50)`.

The first query took 5 minutes to complete. The second query took 40 minutes to complete. There was no other activity on this database during the execution of either query.

Is there any *obvious* reason I may be missing as a still-novice-level database user as to why this could be? The column types being different as they are could not possibly be the cause, right? This is the only difference I can see. **Neither of these two columns exist in any index.**

Any suggestions as to why that second query takes so long would be very helpful.

Comment: What does the query plan say?

Comment: @MitchWheat - yes definitely - I will re-run and grab it and post it here asap.  Thanks.

Comment: @MitchWheat this is a great point.  While I've tried to be diligent in ensuring our DTU allocation is ample, I'm looking at the DTU usage right now in the portal - I see it hit 100% during the first query and during the 2nd query it's maxing out at 60%!  You could be on to something.  So Azure SQL Databases throttle DTU's after you hit 100% at any given point?!?  This is not good!

Comment: It throttles you at the time though using resource governor. It won't let you get into debt by exceeding it in the first query and then claw it back during the second. When you see it at 100% you are potentially being throttled

Comment: What were the previous column contents? Is `CategoryAlt` being made wider? What is the level of internal fragmentation on the table now after the updates?

Comment: Why are you setting 3 million rows to have the exact same values in all rows? I feel like there is something simpler you could do here (like dropping the columns, re-adding them as NULL, and using a view to show KLM/DLM *except* when there's an exception). This will take a lot less space *and* will be easier to change later when you decide you want different defaults.

Comment: And actually dropping the column and re-adding with the desired constant value as a default would also be a metadata only change.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will look into this.  I inherited this from our last DBA, and am trying to keep things running smoothly in the interim until we have a new DBA in place.  In the meantime, my question is about analyzing a cause of difference between 2 queries.  My question is not asking how to do this more efficiently.  It's possible a separate post may be forthcoming for that though.

Comment: Well, doing it a different way will make both queries unnecessary (and therefore 100% more efficient). When you're updating 3 million rows to the same value, you need to think deeper about the problem ... it doesn't matter which one came first or why one runs faster than the other.

Comment: @AaronBertrand agreed.  I'm far from an expert.  Just trying to take it one step at a time in the learning process.I appreciate the input.

Comment: I can only see one likely reason (now that I caught that neither column is indexed) - The `Category` column already has data in most or all rows, and the `CategoryAlt` column either has no data or has very little data. This would minimize the number of page splits when updating Category, and maximize the number for updating CategoryAlt, resulting in a slower process for a CategoryAlt update.

Comment: Also, if the row has a clustered index, page splits tend to be more costly, so this could explain the 8x slowdown.

Comment: @LaughingVergil if it's true that a column with no data would take much longer to update than a column with some data, then I think you've nailed it!  This is in fact the case on the table in question.  I was completely unaware that the existence or non-existence of data in a column could have any effect on an UPDATE statement.